# split vector of strings with partial match

Tags: r

If I have a list of some elements:

```
x = c('abc', 'bbc', 'cd', 'hj', 'aa', 'zz', 'd9', 'jk')
```

I'd like to split it every time there's an `'a'` to create a nested list:

```
[1][[1]] 'abc', 'bbc', 'cd', 'hj'
[2][[1]] 'aa', 'zz', 'd9', 'jk'
```

I tried

```
split(x, 'a')
```

but split doesn't look for partial matches.

Answer (score 2):

Another `base R` possibility could be:

```
split(x, cumsum(nchar(sub("a", "", x, fixed = TRUE)) - nchar(x) != 0))

$`1`
[1] "abc" "bbc" "cd"  "hj" 

$`2`
[1] "aa" "zz" "d9" "jk"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a group  by matching the substring 'a' with `grepl` to a logical vector and then convert to numeric by getting the cumulative sum for distinct groups and use that in `split`

```
split(x, cumsum(grepl('a', x)))
#$`1`
#[1] "abc" "bbc" "cd"  "hj" 

#$`2`
#[1] "aa" "zz" "d9" "jk"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution using `split` + `findInterval` (code is not as short as the answer by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60938102/12158757))

```
split(x,findInterval(seq_along(x),grep("a",x)))
```

such that

```
> split(x,findInterval(seq_along(x),grep("a",x)))
$`1`
[1] "abc" "bbc" "cd"  "hj" 

$`2`
[1] "aa" "zz" "d9" "jk"
```